# Type inference in TypeScript for curried function

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have the following definition for a curried function in TypeScript:

```
interface Curried2<A, B, Z> {
    (_0: A): (_0: B) => Z;
    (_0: A, _1: B): Z;
}
```

I have the following function that should accept a function (curried or not):

```
function apply<T, U>(f: (_0: T) => U, x: T): U {
    return f(x);
}
```

Now, given

```
let curried: Curried2<number, boolean, string> = ...
```

the following works (as expected):

```
apply<number, (_0: boolean) => string>(curried, 4);
```

But TypeScript cannot infer the type on its own:

```
apply(curried, 4);
```

(Even though there is only one overload for `()` which takes *a single value*.) It complains:

```
Argument of type 'Curried2<number, boolean, string>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(_0: number) => string' ...
```

It has correctly inferred `T`, but inferred `U` to be `string`. Why is this? What can I do to make type inference work for me in this case (as explicitly specifying `T` and `U` is too verbose for my taste)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could try this approach:

```
type Curried<T1, T2, T3> = (x: T1) => (y: T2) => T3;

function apply<T, U>(f: (value: T) => U, x: T): U {
    return f(x);
}

//simple demo
var someFunc: Curried<string, number, [string, number]> = x => y => [x, y];
var curriedSomeFunc = apply(someFunc, "string here");
var result1 = curriedSomeFunc(0); //will be ["string here", 0]
var result2 = curriedSomeFunc(1); //will be ["string here", 1]
```

Another try. The syntax is correct but no safety if you pass not a correct function for currying:

```
interface Curried<T1, T2, T3> {
    (x: T1, y: T2): T3;
    (x: T1): (y: T2) => T3
}

let f1 = <Curried<string, number, [string, number]>>
    ((x: string, y: number) => [x, 1]);
let f2 = <Curried<string, number, [string, number]>>
    ((x: string) => (y: number) => [x, y]);

function apply<T, V>(f: (x: T) => V, x: T): V {
    return f(x);
}

let curriedF1 = apply(f1, "42"); //Won't work (no function to curry) but type inference is OK
let curriedF2 = apply(f2, "11"); //Will work and type inference is also OK
```

Comment: In this case I would lose the ability to use the function as a regular uncurried function, so that won't work, unfortunately :(

Comment: That's it! The only difference between your example (in which type inference works) and mine (in which it doesn't) is the order of the overloaded methods of `Curried`. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Now the following won't work anymore: `function applyTwo<S, T, V>(f: (x: S, y: T) => V, x: S, y: T): V { return f(x, y); }; applyTwo(f1, "23", 23);` What, do you think, is the reason for this?

Comment: I don't think it's a good practice to use "overloading" for a function interface. It seems more like a typescript design flaw than a real feature. I would prefer to use currying technique via multiple arrow expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The following now works:

```
interface F1<A, Z> {
    (_0: A): Z;
}

interface F2<A, B, Z> extends F1<A, F1<B, Z>> {
    (_0: A, _1: B): Z;
}

function apply<T, U>(f: F1<T, U>, x: T): U {
    return f(x);
}

function apply2<T, U, V>(f: F2<T, U, V>, x: T, y: U): V {
    return f(x, y);
}

let curried: F2<number, boolean, string> = null;

const x: F1<boolean, string> = apply(curried, 4);
const y: string = apply2(curried, 4, false);
```